# Выбрать в dataframe строки соответствующие условию и 10 строк до и после них

Tags: python, pandas

Допустим у меня есть некий pandas dataframe, в котором лежит один столбец и большое количество строк с числами. Мне нужно выбрать `df[df['test']<5]`, а так же десять строк под строками удовлетворяющими этому условию и десять строк сверху.

Можно ли это как-то сделать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Поскольку строки со значением <5 могут располагаться на расстоянии, меньшем, чем 10 строк, то множественные выборки +/- 10 строк наверняка приведут к множественному же дублированию данных. Поэтому предлагается сначала пометить строки, отвечающие условию, а затем уже распространить выбор вперед и назад на нужное количество строк. Для этого вводится вспомогательный столбец `select`. Таким образом будут помечены и затем отобраны все нужные строки без дублирования.

Вариант с `ffill()` и `bfill()`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'test': np.random.randint(4, 20, 100), 'select': None})
df.loc[df["test"] < 5, 'select'] = True  # помечаем строки, соответствующие условию, как True, в столбце select
df.select = df.select.ffill(limit=10).bfill(limit=10)  # заполняем None вниз и вверх не более чем на 10 строк в каждую сторону
print(df.dropna())  # удаляем оставшиеся строки с None и выводим результат
```

```
    test select
21     7   True # -10 строк для первого случая <5
22    13   True
23     9   True
24     6   True
25     9   True
26     7   True # -5 строк для первого случая <5 и одновременно -10 строк для второго случая <5
27    10   True # -4 строки для первого случая <5 и одновременно -9 строк для второго случая <5
28    19   True # и так далее
29     5   True
30     9   True
31     4   True # <5 первый случай
32    13   True
33     5   True
34    19   True
35     9   True
36     4   True # <5 второй случай
37    12   True
38    11   True
...
67     6   True
68    12   True
69    17   True
70    14   True
71    16   True
72    19   True
```

Answer (score 2):

Можно. Например так:

```
for i in df[df["test"]<5].index:
    print(df.iloc[i-10:i+10,:])
```